# Accepted merge requests author not shown as contributor

Tags: github, open-source, git-merge, pull-request

Recently I've started a new open source android project on GitHub ([Open Weather App](https://github.com/ardovic/Open-Weather-App)). One person forked the repository and made some changes, then he created a pull request and I accepted it by pressing this green button:

[image]

Everything worked just fine, the pull request was merged into master. However, the problem is that he did not appear in the contributors list. It still does say 1 contributor, which is me:

[image]

**What could be the reason for him not to appear on the list, and how can I solve this issue?**

I feel responsibility for him. I even added him to collaborators list, yet he still does not appear as a contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [Contributions that are counted](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) are 3 points listed which must be met by a contributor:

I checked your repo and the pull request and it seems like this point is not met:

> The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub
>   account

Comment: We are currently looking into solving the issue. Can you suggest us what to do step-by-step?

Comment: I think changing your local git config Email to a different Email than you have @github is enough

Comment: Sry i mean your global git config Email should be the same as you use with GitHub.

Comment: Yes, you are right `- git config --global user.email "email@example.com"` - this command solved our issue helped

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not described here?

[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)

Comment: Yes, yesterday I've spent all evening researching this problem, this was one of the first articles I've read. I've checked everything it suggested, unfortunately it doesn't appear to solve the issue.